# Shell script won't let go of the prompt when it's finished being executed

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to re-create a command I had when I was using tmux called `ta` (to all) that was meant to execute a given command in all visible panes, but in this case to all visible shells in the current workspace as I'm now using a tiling window manager.

I got the missing part I was needing to make this work in a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663137/181414).

The command works simply, first I trap a signal (`SIGUSR2` in this case, based on the advice in that question).

Then when I want to send a command I:

- Write out the command (along with a guard clause checking the workspace) to a file in configured location
- Send the signal to all shells (zsh in this case)
- Which causes the shells to source the script at the configured location
- Which will only execute if the shell is in the current workspace

Trapping the command (add this somewhere in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# Add trap for ta command
export USR2_COMMAND_FILE=$HOME/.ta_executable
export TA_SHELL="zsh"
trap '[[ -r $USR2_COMMAND_FILE ]] && . $USR2_COMMAND_FILE' USR2
```

The script(`~/dir/in/$PATH/ta`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

to_execute="$@"
workspace="$(xdotool get_desktop)"
script="if [[ \"$workspace\" == \"\$(xdotool get_desktop)\" ]]; then $to_execute; fi"
script_location="$USR2_COMMAND_FILE"

echo $script > $script_location

for pid in $(pgrep "$TA_SHELL"); do
    kill -SIGUSR2 $pid
done
```

The issue is that the commands execute in all shells **but** then don't seem to let go of the prompt (is that the right way to say it?), I have to move to that shell and then press `<enter>` manually to make it finish, I've tried various things but nothing seems to work.

How do I get it let go of the prompt?

Comment: So, if I get this right, it's similar to how if you do just `trap 'echo hello' USR2` in the zsh, then `kill -USR2 $(pidof zsh)` from another shell and see `hello` printed just after the prompt, but the shell doesn't print a new prompt after it?

Comment: @ilkkachu Exactly! I'm sorry if I wasn't clear but I genuinely wasn't sure how bet to describe it or if there was even specific terminology.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the prompt back when running \`at' from terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505245/how-do-i-get-the-prompt-back-when-running-at-from-terminal)

Comment: I don't quite understand what part you're referring to,  Is it the `exit 0` command? or the answer? Or the fact that they seem to be saying that the prompt is there? What would be helpful is a command to forcibly refresh the prompt or something like that.